# how to point to next record shown in access table?

Tags: vb6

I am a newbie to Access and I have a short question.  I have a table and I am using this table to display it in my listbox (form) using vb.  the table include a date which I want to sort but each date record was entered into table at random times.  So, when I sort this column, the first record is showing on the top of the table but this can be e.g. record number 23.  Therefore, when I use the method .MoveNext in my code it will point to record number 1 and not what's showing on the table.  how do I point to next record showing on the table?

is this clear?

Thanks so much,

BK

Comment: Its not very clear. Think about adding some code in and be more specific in the problem you are having.

Comment: in your recordset query, use order by clause on the date